# Does the Blue Trinket reveal stealthed units?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, does the blue trinket reveal stealthed targets?

If you are sighted with the Blue Trinket, and you immediately enter stealth, will it still reveal you or will you enter stealth as normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will still be revealed if you are spotted BEFORE you enter stealth**

**You will NOT be revealed if you are already stealthed (as said in the tooltip)**

> Reveals small location within 2500 / 3500 range for 2 seconds (120 second cooldown). Enemy champions hit will be revealed for 5 seconds. This does not affect stealth champions.

this was discussed in a [forumpost](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=4225906) and no patch affected it since then.

If you want to counter champions that rely on stealth (Akali, Shaco, ...) I recommend [Oracle's Lens](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle's_Lens). It lasts longer, reveals wards and has a pretty low cooldown.

Comment: This isn't quite right - it only reveals you if it is used before you enter stealth. It will keep vision on you then but it won't reveal if you are already stealthed.

Comment: yes. this is what I said. But I'll add it to the answer to make it clear.

Comment: Wait, just so I get this right: If I get spotted by the blue trinket and then enter stealth, I will still be visible to the enemy for the duration of the blue trinket? For example, an Akali gets spotted by the Orb, and then enters her shroud. Will she stay visible while the Orb is active?

Comment: @Toby exactly like that